# Java Socket Problems

Tags: java, sockets, client, chat, communication

So the end result of my program is an updating game client, but what i have so far is a server that is able to accept multiple connections, and a client that connects to the server. this is the code for the client portion:

```
public void client() {
    Socket socket = null;
    ObjectInputStream in = null;
    ObjectOutputStream out = null;

    try {
        socket = new Socket(IP, Integer.parseInt(port));
        in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    do {
        // have a conversation
        try {
            message = (String) in.readObject();
            System.out.println("\n" + message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("\n idk wtf that user sent!");
        }
    } while (!message.equals("CLIENT - END")); // When the user types "END"

    System.err.println("CLOSED!!!");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

and this is the code for the server portion:

```
public void run() {
    // where everything happens
    System.out.println("server- connected");
    try {
        in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        out.writeObject("hi");
        out.flush();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        out.writeObject("close");
        out.flush();
        System.out.println("closed");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

now, i am running into this problem where, when my server sends the object `"hi"` the client appears to not receive it. i'm not totally sure if it does, but if it is getting it, it isnt printing it out like i wanted. i previously have made a chat program that does this same thing, and i pretty much copied it to this, but it isnt communicating. the most i get is the confirmation that they are connected. im not sure what is going on, but any help would be appreciated! thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you getting the output of the line System.out.println("server- connected");?

Comment: yes i do. the problems start happening when i try to send the objects

Comment: Have you tried sending objects? as JSON encoded objects? [check this post](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/260789-sending-json-objects-through-tcp/)

Comment: Do you really need ObjectInputStream / ObjectOutputStream? I can see only Strings in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create the ObjectOutputStreams *before* the ObjectInputStreams and flush them immediately after creation.

the *constructor* of an ObjectInputStream reads the stream header.  this stream header is written by the *constructor* of the ObjectOutputStream (kind of an ugly implementation, but it is what it is).  if you construct the OIS's first, they hang waiting for the header bytes.

Comment: what is the reason for that?

Comment: agreed, that was an amazingly simple solution, but why did it happen?

Comment: @wbAnon - added explanation.  this a fairly well-known gotcha when combining sockets and Object streams in java.